# Loop until satisfied with LIST

Tags: python, loops, grouping

This is my code for generating groups with n members, and x groups. Then rates each group depending on how many similar numbers there are in each group e.g. (1,1,1,1)=1 since only 1 number, however (1,2,3,3)=3 since there are 3 numbers. I tried putting a loop on it until the rate for any of the 9 groups in this place went below a certain z value, however for some reason it didn't work. Can anyone suggest a way to loop this system based on the rating numbers at the end?

```
import numpy
import math
import random
members=4
n_groups =4
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
#print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)


my_groups =g

def get_rating(group):
    return len(set(group))


for each_grp in my_groups:  
    print(get_rating(each_grp))
```

Output in this case:
[[1, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 1]]
    4
    3
    3
    4

Ive simplified it down to 4 members, 4 groups:

[[1, 4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 1]]
4(since group 1 has 4 different numbers)
3(since group 2 has 3 different numbers)
3(since group 3 has 3 different numbers)
4(since group 4 has 4 different numbers)

The things in the square brackets are the 4 groups, the 4 numbers below rate it. I was trying to get a loop that would keep trying it until say one of the 4 rating numbers for each group at the end went down to 1, then would stop

So I want a loop that would keep generating new groups until the rating numbers below the groups ( in this case: 4,3,3,4) were below a certain value like 2,2,2,2

Comment: I ran this and I can't make sense of the output in relation to your question. What exactly isn't working here? What should it look like?

Comment: Show us some sample input and output.

Comment: Edited it with sample

Comment: Everything is working but I wanted to add a loop until the number in the rating system at the bottom were a certain number for example 2>

Comment: Still unclear. A loop that would keep trying what?

Comment: A loop that would keep trying to get different groups to get the best outcome, e.g. (1,1,1,1) is perfect (1,1,1,2) is less good but better than (4,2,3,1). So my rating system rates these fine at the moment, but i wanted to add a loop until the rating is the best for one group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `numpy` for that

```python
import numpy as np

def get_groups(members, n_groups):
    return np.random.randint(1, 5, (n_groups, members))

g = get_groups(4, 4)
while not 1 in [np.unique(sub_g).shape[0] for sub_g in g]:
    g = get_groups(4, 4)
```

Where:

1. `np.random.randint(1, 5 (n_groups, members))` generates `n_groups` groups of length `members` filled with random values in the `range(1, 5)`
2. `np.unique(sub_g).shape[0]` gets your rating (number of unique values in group)
3. `[np.unique(sub_g).shape[0] for sub_g in g]` repeats the former step for each group in `g`
4. `while not 1 in` repeats the loop until value `1` is found in the list computed above (all values in a group are equal)
5. `g = get_groups(4, 4)` repeats step 1

Answer (score 1):

One somewhat naive approach would to wrap your whole program into a while loop that checks all the groups for the score.  Something like:

```
# WARNING, UNTESTED CODE
my_groups = []
while any([get_rating(g) for g in groups] lambda x: x < 2):
  # ...Do e'rythang else...
```

A more sensible approach would be to look at your groups one by one and get the rating each time *before* you write it

*** Updated with working code ***

```
import numpy
import math
import random
members=4
n_groups =4
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
#print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

def get_rating(group):
  return len(set(group))


with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
  for i in range(n_groups):
    group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]

    # right here
    while(get_rating(group) < 2):
      # Do it again
      random.shuffle(participants)
      group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]

    # now right it
    for participant in group:
        tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
    tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)


my_groups =g

for each_grp in my_groups:  
    print(get_rating(each_grp))
```

Comment: ok thanks! How would this integrate into my code? Just tried putting bits in, not sure how it fits in Thanks though

Comment: Updated with the full program.  You owe me that A+ :-)

Comment: Thank you :) A****